# Samba creates new files with no write Permissions for Group/Others

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

I am running Samba 4.7.6 on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install inside an ESXi Machine. The shares work fine to view but when I or my wife try to create a new file or directory from Windows, we get the old no permissions message.  So for me I just go to putty and run chmod -R etc, and bob's your uncle.  My wife on the other hand just wants things to work.

So I create a new directory and I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 Mar 10 20:32  test_directory
```

So this is OK so long as I don't want to do anything in the direcory as I am user `rod` not `nobody` So with the group set to `nogroup`, I would be able to write, except that the new directory is created with group not having write permissions.  Now I used `nobody:nogroup` because this was a open shared file that anyone that can get onto the network is able to get into.

The `/shares/shared` except from the `smb.conf` is below.

```
path = /shares/shared
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
null passwords = yes
create mask = 0777
force user = nobody
force group = nogroup
```

Any suggestions about how I can make this shared Samba folder create files that `nogroup` has write permissions?

Comment: user nobody and nogroup is not a good idea. nobody is a system user that is used to run services e.g. apache and samba on Linux distros. Root has to start the service and then pass on control to the user nobody.  Maybe a guest account could [suite your needs](https://superuser.com/questions/1081542/how-to-allow-guest-access-in-samba)

Comment: Thanks for the info about the nobody user, I will correct that and give the tip in the attatched thread a try.

Comment: I would create a group 'couple' (for instance), add the two of you in it and modify ´force group` to `couple` , change the group owernship to it and finally, give it write permission.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen: Sorry, it has been forever since I have had an opportunity to play with this.  I will try that as well.  The problem is mostly gone, but there are still folders she cannot write to after creating them.  Thanks for this.